# C# Order List by List of Internal Properties

Tags: c#, list, collections

Suppose I have an object like so..

```
public class Child
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Mother
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Child child;
}
```

And now I have a list of Mothers

```
List<Mother>
```

I already have `List<Child>` ordered

Child is 1 to 1 with Mother.

I'd like to order the list of Mother based of the order of `List<Child>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are all of those members really private fields, or did you just leave off the access modifiers?

Comment: What are you trying to order them by? Any shouldn't company be a one to many?

Comment: The example is strictly hypothetical. I'll update the example to prevent confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "order the list of Mother based on order of List<Child>" ? There is no list of Mothers or Childs in your example, so we don't know how the List<Child> was ordered in the first place. Also, Child is not 1 to 1 with Mother in real life, since Mothers can have more than 1 child. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Mother should contain a list of Child making it a one to many. When that is done, you can then sort the Mothers by your criteria, and for each mother, sort their Children.

Comment: Please, people, curb your pedantry. These mothers and children might not be exactly that in the real life problem of the questioner. They might be just a bit poorly chosen example to describe the correspondence of the actual entities.

Comment: You guys are hopeless. It's just a hypothetical. Me saying it's 1 to 1 means its one to one. xjuice, good stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lists are equinumerous and all mothers have child and vice versa, then this works out-of-the-box. If there are more mothers than children or mothers whose child is not on the children's list, then those mothers are not returned. Similarly, if there are more children than mothers or children whose mother is not on the mothers' list, then motjers of those children are not returned.

```
public IEnumerable<Mother> GetOrderedMothersByChildren(
    IEnumerable<Mother> mothers, IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        var mother = mothers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Child == child);
        if (mother != null)
            yield return mother;
    }
}

//Usage
var orderedMothers = GetOrderedMothersByChildren(mothers, children).ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. Appreciate that